# R: Extract character string elements to new columns

Tags: r, string, substring, dplyr

I have a data frame in R with 1000 rows, the variable, var1_string is a character string that looks like this:

```
var_1_ID   var1_string
1          "object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1, object.subfeature.ID = 55555, object.subfeature.e1 = 1, object.subfeature.e2 = False, object.subfeature.ID = 66666,object.subfeature.e1 = 2, object.subfeature.e4 = 50 object.subfeature.e9 = abc, object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, object.feature = ab.."
2          "object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1, object.subfeature.ID = 55555, object.subfeature.e1 = 1, object.subfeature.e2 = False, object.subfeature.ID = 66666,object.subfeature.e1 = 2, object.subfeature.e4 = 50 object.subfeature.e9 = abc, object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, object.feature = ab.."

and so on for n rows...
```

Is there a quick way to extract the following into new columns:

new_column_1  =`"object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1"`

new_column_2 to new_column_n would contain `"object.subfeature.ID`.... to the next `object.subfeature.ID`, and so on until there are no more sub-features.....

so in this example:

new_column_2 = `object.subfeature.ID = 55555, object.subfeature.e1 = 1, object.subfeature.e2 = False`,

then the next column contains the next  `object.subfeature.ID` block, e.g. `object.subfeature.ID = 66666,object.subfeature.e1 = 2, object.subfeature.e4 = 50`

and finally a separate column for all  `object.features`..\

e.g. desired output:

```
Var_1_ID   Var1_string      New_col1                             New_col2                                                                         New_col3
1          String as above  object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1   object.subfeature.ID = 55555,  object.subfeature.e1 = 1, object.subfeature.e2 = False                    object.subfeature.ID = 66666,object.subfeature.e1 = 2, object.subfeature.e4 = 50 
                            object.subfeature.e9 = abc, object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, object.feature = ab..
2          String as above  object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1
```

Is there a way using substring? or would you have to use `stringr::str_extract /   dplyr::mutate(strsplit...`) ?

Note: there could be any number of object.subfeatures e.g `object.subfeature.ID = 55555 and its parts, from 0 to n

Comment: please post into console `dput(YOURDATA[1:3,])` and post the result HERE!

Comment: tidyr separate, but how would you deal with varried string lengths with  differing numbers of elements in,  but still breaking into new columns as above?

Comment: description of expected output is poor

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a good start

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(Var_1_ID = c(1,2), Var1_string = c("object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1, object.subfeature.ID = 55555, object.subfeature.e1 = 1, object.subfeature.e2 = False, object.subfeature.ID = 66666,object.subfeature.e1 = 2, object.subfeature.e4 = 50 object.subfeature.e9 = abc, object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd", "object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1, object.subfeature.ID = 55555, object.subfeature.e1 = 1, object.subfeature.e2 = False, object.subfeature.ID = 66666,object.subfeature.e1 = 2, object.subfeature.e4 = 50 object.subfeature.e9 = abc, object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd"))

df2 <- df %>% mutate(newstring = str_split(Var1_string, ",")) %>% 
    unnest() %>%
    separate(newstring, into = c("col", "val"), sep = "=") %>% 
    select(-Var1_string)%>%
    group_by(Var_1_ID)%>%
    mutate(key = row_number())%>%
    unite("new_var", key, col, sep = "_")%>%
    spread(new_var, val)

df2
  Var_1_ID `1_object.ID ` `10_ object.featu… `2_ object.ID.N… `3_ object.subfea… 
1        1 " 00001"       " cd"              " 1"             " 55555"           " 1"           
2        2 " 00001"       " cd"              " 1"             " 55555"           " 1"
```

Note that I had to add a nuber to the variable in order to make each column unique for spreading.

Comment: Thanks, isn't this making additional rows though? Instead of spliting the string across new columns?

Comment: This is the long format. You’re talking about the wide format. I didn’t have time to play around with it for too long, but you can generally use tidy::spread to go from long to wide

Comment: This not what OP asked for. OP need to separate one column into multiple columns.

Comment: Since not all of your strings in col are unique per group, I would recommend grouping by ID, generating a unique id code per group, uniting the unique key with the string and then spreading the data. If you have trouble, I can come back to it later this afternoon

Comment: @AndS.that would be useful please

Comment: Let me know if that’s more like what you’re looking for

Comment: @AndS.  Kind of, updated the question, sorry I wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

```
#Prepare data to be split on `;`
data$Var1_string <- gsub("(object.ID.N = [0-9]),",'\\1;',data$Var1_string)
data$Var1_string <- gsub("(object.subfeature.e[0-9] = [0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^a-z]",'\\1;',data$Var1_string)
data$Var1_string <- gsub("(object.subfeature.ID = [0-9a-zA-Z]+)[^a-z]",'\\1;',data$Var1_string)

ncol <- max(lengths(strsplit(data$Var1_string,split = ';')))

library(tidyr)
data <- data %>% separate(Var1_string,into = paste0('Col',1:ncol),sep=';',remove = FALSE)

colnames(data)[3:11] <- c('New_col','object.subfeature.ID.e1','object.subfeature.e1','object.subfeature.e2','object.subfeature.ID.e11','object.subfeature.e11','object.subfeature.e14','object.subfeature.e19','object.features')

data %>% mutate_at(vars(contains('object.subfeature')), 
                  .funs = funs(gsub("object.subfeature.e[0-9] = |object.subfeature.ID = ", '', .)))

  Var_1_ID
1        1
2        2

Var1_string
1 object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1; object.subfeature.ID = 55555; object.subfeature.e1 = 1; object.subfeature.e2 = False; object.subfeature.ID = 66666;object.subfeature.e1 = 2; object.subfeature.e4 = 50;object.subfeature.e9 = abc; object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, object.feature = ab..
2 object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1; object.subfeature.ID = 55555; object.subfeature.e1 = 1; object.subfeature.e2 = False; object.subfeature.ID = 66666;object.subfeature.e1 = 2; object.subfeature.e4 = 50;object.subfeature.e9 = abc; object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, object.feature = ab..
                         New_col object.subfeature.ID.e1 object.subfeature.e1
1 object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1                   55555                    1
2 object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1                   55555                    1
object.subfeature.e2 object.subfeature.ID.e11 object.subfeature.e11 object.subfeature.e14
 1                False                    66666                     2                    50
 2                False                    66666                     2                    50
 object.subfeature.e19                                                 
 object.features
 1                   abc  object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, 
 object.feature = ab..
 2                   abc  object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, 
 object.feature = ab..
```

## Data

```
 data <- read.table(text="
         Var_1_ID   Var1_string
         1          'object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1, object.subfeature.ID = 55555, object.subfeature.e1 = 1, object.subfeature.e2 = False, object.subfeature.ID = 66666,object.subfeature.e1 = 2, object.subfeature.e4 = 50 object.subfeature.e9 = abc, object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, object.feature = ab..'
         2          'object.ID = 00001, object.ID.N = 1, object.subfeature.ID = 55555, object.subfeature.e1 = 1, object.subfeature.e2 = False, object.subfeature.ID = 66666,object.subfeature.e1 = 2, object.subfeature.e4 = 50 object.subfeature.e9 = abc, object.feature = 3, object.feature = cd, object.feature = ab..'
               ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```